# Eclipse Git plugin always throws an error when I do a commit and push action

Tags: eclipse, git

I have the next problem with eclipse git plugin. With the same project, with other git clients such as SourceTree I don't have this problem.

I have, for example, the next branch, with a simple modification for commit and pushing. I have just done a pull and I don't have changes for retrieving from the remote branch:

[image]

I add the change to the index:

[image]

Then, when I push on "Commit and Push" button, I have the next error:

[image]

And eclipse shows that I have changes for retrieving and pushing. The last one is obvious because It's my last commit on my local repository, but I don't understand the reason because eclipse doesn't do both, the commit and the push, without throwing any error.

[image]

As I said before, with the same project and local repository, with SourceTree, I don't have this problem.

I will be grateful if somebody can help me with this issue, please.

Comment: It looks like you did only a _Fetch_ instead of a _Pull_ before _Commit and Push_.

Comment: @howlger Before commit and push I have done a pull. This happens for each commit and pull I want to do, but only with eclipse git plugin. Besides this, eclipse always shows the same changes number for pulling than pushing.

Comment: If you also used the command line for the same repository, do a refresh first. Otherwise check in the _History_ view where the problem is: pull, commit or push.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution for this problem. As I said in my post, the problem only happens in eGIT and the same action works successfully in both, sourcetree and command line clients.

In fact, eGIT works fine too. The problem was that for each commit and push I made, I wanted to import the last text I had written in prior commits. For that, I was using the button [image]. I didn't read well that the meaning of this button is "Amend (Edit Previos Commit)". I thought this button meant "Retrieve the last commit text".

If I type inside the box without pushing this button, I have the correct behaviour in the commit and push action.

As SourceTree has, it would be interesting eGIT could implement a button with the last commit texts you have made, in order to reuse them if we want.

However, thank you very much for all of you who has spent your time trying to help me. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting: `rejected - non-fast-forward` means that the remote repository is rejecting your push because it cannot apply your commits automatically. This error occurs when for example there's a situation like this:

```
Remote:  A -> B -> X
Local:   A -> B -> Y (error when pushing)
```

i.e. the repository cannot apply your commits because your history and the remote history diverged. A valid example:

```
Remote:  A -> B
Local:   A -> B -> Y (no error when pushing)
```

In the second example the remote repository can easily do a fast-forward.

To see the problem, open the repository in the `History` view in Eclipse and find your branch and the remote one. Then merge or rebase your branch with the remote one.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This is how GIT works. As I said in my post, the problem should be something in EGIT, because with sourcetree and command line it works successfully. The problem was mine, due to a minunderstanting of Staging view in EGIT. I will expose the solution as a response in my post, so if someone has the same problem, he don't spend a lot of time with this topic.